# How to get data in an array in a pattern?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, floating-point

I am trying to get the x and y values out of a PointCloud2 data. This data is stored in an array in bytes of float32's. My question is, how can I get only the x and y data?

I will add a snippet of what the PointCloud2 data looks like, but for now I'd like to just be able to get the x - data. So for every 16 values, I only want the first 4 (I want the first 4 as this is how it is ordered and because the float32's are decomposed into 4 bytes each).

My original thought process was just to use a loop, but I am worried this may be too slow. This is as my array has more than 2000 values and I am getting 15 of these arrays per second. Is there any other way of doing this?

```
  seq: 296
  stamp: 
    secs: 1553456947
    nsecs: 421859979
  frame_id: "cloud"
height: 1
width: 811
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "intensity"
    offset: 12
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 16
row_step: 12976
data: [108, 171, 8, 191, 107, 171, 8, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 113, 70, 167, 
197, 8, 191, 103, 95, 10, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 115, 70, 99, 101, 9, 191,
 127, 161, 12, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 106, 70, 99, 50, 5, 191, 202, 237, 9,
 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 82, 70, 200, 22, 235, 190, 200, 74, 246, 190, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 132, 52, 70, 186, 111, 255, 190, 99, 95, 7, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24,
 60, 70, 227, 1, 8, 191, 89, 217, 17, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 93, 70, 216, 
183, 8, 191, 245, 84, 20, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236, 112, 70, 195, 94, 8, 191,
 64, 177, 21, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...
```

I would also like to add that I am a beginner at this sort of thing. I spoke with my friend and he said using mutex threading for this, but that seems way over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: Threads aren't all that useful in reading a file. Only one can be reading the file at a time. You could read the whole file into memory, divide the the memory up into blocks and fire those blocks to threads to parse, but it's tricky to chop up a text file because the numbers are all different sizes. I suggest starting with dumb and stupid. This gives you a baseline you can improve upon if it is too slow. It's also something you can ask about at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) if it's not fast enough for your needs.

Comment: Ah ok thank you I'll look into code review. Just for reference though I'm running this from ROS and this data is posted onto a topic that I'll subscribe to. I'm not really sure how ROS handles data but i don't think it would be the same as reading from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you'll be surprised how fast modern hardware can loop through 30000 points.

You should start off with your loop and some basic considerations. For example, for storage of our X/Y coordinates in a vector, reserve the required space in the vector before you enter your loop to avoid extra memory allocations. Once you have your loop working, evaluate the performance and maybe post another question if you think that your code is too slow.

A helpful quote by Donald E. Knuth that may apply:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Edit; to provide some context: We had an application running on a low end i5 processor collecting 76,800 3D points at 15 fps via the Kinect SDK or via OpenNI (different sensor). We'd loop through the points and apply a basic transformation before storing each point into a pcl::PointCloud. We'd then loop through the point cloud points again for some analysis. The analysis portion far outweighed the cost of any basic loop. You will probably end up worrying about optimizing whatever evaluation logic you want apply to your data rather than basic things such as looping over the points.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all. He or she has a large array of bytes that contains the data in the format layed out in the `fields:` description. So each record has obviously 16 bytes. He or she wants to extract the x and y values as floats from the blob of data and asks **how**. That has nothing to do with your answer, AFAICT.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The OP asks whether 'there is any other way of doing this' (other than a basic loop) and my answer is, essentially, 'yes, but stick to the basic loop'. My point of view is that he/she would be ill-advised to try anything else at this stage since the basic loop (which OP implies he/she knows how to implement) should perform very well.

Comment: Thank you for your response that makes sense to me. I am still a bit concerned as I am running this on a raspberry pi with lubuntu and Ros. The raspberry has already crashed with some more intensive applications such as when making packages so that's why I was a bit concerned. I'll definitely try the loop and go from there!

Comment: @Pfrances Although the Pi is less powerful than even our low end i5 the basic single threaded loop is still the best option. I doubt very much that there is any benefit in copying coordinates in some multi-threaded way for that little data.